# How to Create New Columns Based on Row Categories Matching?

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, tidyverse

I'm trying to add new columns to my dataframe based on matching values in rows. A sample of my starting data is:

```
    ex <- structure(list(reg_desc = c("1-Northeast Region", "1-Northeast Region", 
"1-Northeast Region", "1-Northeast Region", "1-Northeast Region"
), state = c("04-Connecticut", "05-Maine", "04-Connecticut", 
"05-Maine", NA), trigger_city = c("14860-Bridgeport-Stamford-Norwalk", 
"12620-Bangor", NA, NA, NA), Category = c("M", "M", "S", "S", 
"R"), Cred_Fac = c(0, 0, 0.317804971641414, 0, 1), Mean = c(50323.3311111111, 
48944.4266666667, 44220.8220792079, 43724.1495, 50492.0654351396
)), row.names = c(1L, 7L, 118L, 119L, 136L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: original]

But now I'd like to find a way where, if states and regions match, to append those values by creating new columns. I have a category column where M is for metropolitan, S is for state, and R is for region. I'd like to append the state info and region infos to any row that is one level below. My final output would look like:

```
hi1 <- data.frame(reg_desc = c("1-Northeast Region", "1-Northeast Region", 
                                  "1-Northeast Region", "1-Northeast Region", "1-Northeast Region"
), state = c("04-Connecticut", "05-Maine", "04-Connecticut", 
             "05-Maine", NA), trigger_city = c("14860-Bridgeport-Stamford-Norwalk", 
                                               "12620-Bangor", NA, NA, NA), Category = c("M", "M", "S", "S", 
                                                                                         "R"), Cred_Fac = c(0, 0, 0.317804971641414, 0, 1), Mean = c(50323.3311111111, 
                                                                                                                                                     48944.4266666667, 44220.8220792079, 43724.1495, 50492.0654351396),
State_Cred_Fac = c(0.317805,0.000000,NA,NA,NA),Mean_State = c(44220.82,43724.15,NA,NA,NA),
Reg_Cred_Fac = c(1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,NA),
Mean_Region = c(50492.07,50492.07,50492.07,50492.07,NA))
```

[image: new]

Is there any way I could get a result like this without having to do it manually? Thanks in advance

Comment: How are those values selected in the 4 new columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you problem correctly one possible solution is using join operations (in this case from the dplyr package):

```
library(dplyr)

ex %>%  
  dplyr::left_join(ex %>% 
                     dplyr::filter(is.na(trigger_city) & !is.na(state)) %>% 
                     dplyr::select(state, Cred_Fac, Mean),
                   by = "state"
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(ex %>% 
                     dplyr::filter(is.na(trigger_city) & is.na(state)) %>% 
                     dplyr::select(reg_desc, Cred_Fac, Mean),
                   by = "reg_desc"
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Cred_Fac.y = ifelse(is.na(trigger_city), NA, Cred_Fac.y),
                Mean.y = ifelse(is.na(trigger_city), NA, Mean.y),
                Cred_Fac = ifelse(is.na(state), NA, Cred_Fac),
                Mean = ifelse(is.na(state), NA, Mean)) %>%
  dplyr::select(reg_desc = 1, state = 2, trigger_city = 3, Category = 4, Cred_Fac = 5, Mean = 6, State_Cred_Fac = 7, Mean_State = 8, Reg_Cred_Fac= 9, Mean_Region = 10)

     reg_desc          state                      trigger_city Category Cred_Fac     Mean State_Cred_Fac Mean_State Reg_Cred_Fac Mean_Region
1 1-Northeast Region 04-Connecticut 14860-Bridgeport-Stamford-Norwalk        M   0.000000 50323.33   0.317805 44220.82        1 50492.07
2 1-Northeast Region       05-Maine                      12620-Bangor        M   0.000000 48944.43   0.000000 43724.15        1 50492.07
3 1-Northeast Region 04-Connecticut                              <NA>        S   0.317805 44220.82         NA       NA        1 50492.07
4 1-Northeast Region       05-Maine                              <NA>        S   0.000000 43724.15         NA       NA        1 50492.07
5 1-Northeast Region           <NA>                              <NA>        R   1.000000 50492.07         NA       NA       NA       NA
```